# general question about database

Tags: mysql, scalability

I've kinda silly question. I have a small community website. I'm thinking to make specific pages which can be viewed only by the members who have permission. So I suppose i will add each member ID in the database and when a member will try to access the page then i will first check if the member is logged in and then i will check the user ID, if it exists in the database table of users which have permission to view that content. Now Im just wondering if the database grows up, wont it take a long time to check everythng before loading the page?

Comment: What's the website running? I assume PHP given you're mentioning MySQL? I would add an "authorized" token to the session at the time it's necessary, and hold on to it, so it doesn't keep pinging every visit to the page.

Answer (score 0):

> [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) (Donald Knuth)

You can easily handle several millions of users with a single database, so that won't be a problem until your community is huge. When you reach that step, you can switch to more scalable DB solutions like [Cassandra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra).

Having that said, take Brad Christie's comment into account, and use a reasonable identity management that won't thrash your database unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

"a long time" is subjective and depends on many factors.  For a small community website, you will likely not run into any issues with the method you've described.  Still, it is considered best practice, and will speed up queries significantly, if you make use of proper indexes.  Columns that will be queried against, such as the user ID, should be indexed.  Not using an index means that MySQL has to read every record in your table and check to see if it matches your criteria.

This article may be of use to you:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm

Also, if you are concerned about how your site will perform when your dataset grows, consider populating it with a bunch of dummy data and running a few tests.  This site will help you generate a bunch of data to put in your database.

http://www.generatedata.com/#about

Lastly, if pages are not specific to a particular person or small group of people, consider using more general buckets for access control.  For example, if only admins can view a page, tie that page to an "admin" permission and note which users are admins.  Then, you can do a quick check to see what type or types of user a particular person is, and decide to show them the page or not.  This type of system is typically refered to as an Access Control List (ACL).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list